# How to display link in validation as part of string?

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik

I have `USM-Registration.json` file for english, german and which is file for translation React app.

**USM-Registration.json**

```
  "ResponseError": {
     "error": {
        "already.exists": "Social security number already exists. Please login at {{link}}."
      },
    },
```

Note that I have `{{link}}` which will be dynamically provided but I have an issue with that.

I am using formik and validation with yup but I am unable to pass link as part of string, but when I provide string, works ok.

How to parse that link and display it properly?

```
 import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

  const { t } = useTranslation()

  ...rest of the code...

  ssn: string()
    .test(
      'ssn',
      t(
        'USM-Registration:ResponseError.error.already.exists',
        'Social security number already exists. Please login at domain.com.',
        {link: linkShouldBeHere}
      ),
      function(value) {
        return
      },
    ),
```

To display an error , I am using error and helperText on input

```
    error={!!form.errors.ssn}
    helperText={form.errors.ssn}
```

Comment: you might need to use the Trans component: https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

Comment: or set excapeValue: false in the interpolation options => t('key', { interpolation: { escapeValue: false } }) => https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation#unescape

Comment: Thank you @adrai, I have resolved the issue with Trans component. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue with `<Trans>` component from `react-i18next`

```
  // Used for Social Security number validation message
  const link = {
    url: 'https://example.com',
    name: 'example.com',
  };

  // Conditionally render form validation error message received from api
  const apiErrorCondition = apiErrorMessage && !form.errors.ssn;

  return (
    <div>
      {apiErrorCondition ? (
        <div>
          <Trans
            i18nKey={`USM-Registration:ResponseError.${apiErrorMessage}`}
            t={t}
            values={{ link }}
            components={{
              code: (
                <a
                  style={{ textDecoration: 'underline' }}
                  href={link.url}
                  target="_blank"
                >
                  {link.name}
                </a>
              ),
            }}
          />
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
```

and change translation to

`"already.exists": "Social security number already exists. Please login at <code>{{link.name}}</code>.",`